# Adding shortcode field to edit gallery / Gallery Settings

Tags: shortcode, gallery

I want to add a field to the Add Media / Edit Gallery / Gallery Settings column which is able to accept shortcodes.

I want to do this so that I can add a Cart66 shortcode which will "render" an add to cart button and price to individual thumbnails in the relevant gallery page.

Any help much appreciated.